# Apply an equation over a data series without a for loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to apply the following formulation over a set of huge data series (~525600 x 10).
The formulation is:
[image]

I've applied the following code to apply the formulation, but it is tooooo slow:

```
ntr=10; % number of different sets of data series
phi=90; % days
phivec=1:1/24:2*phi+1; % for hourly data

cte=sum(10.^(phivec./phi));
phivec=repmat(phivec',[1,ntr]);
for i = 2*24*phi+1:nti % size(Omega)=>(ntr,nti)
    OmegaEQ(i,:)=sum(Omega(i-24*phi*2:i,:).*10.^(phivec./phi))./cte;
end
```

Can someone help me to to it faster?

Comment: Your first sum has a closed form: $\frac{10^{-2 \phi } \left(10^{2 \phi +1}-1\right)}{9 \phi }$ but I'm guessing it's the second sum that's giving you trouble?

Comment: Exactly, I'm doing the loop over almost the full data series, and it is too slow.

Comment: Pre-allocating `OmegaEQ` before the loop should give you significant speed improvements, currently it's just growing each iteration. You also haven't defined `Omega` in this example, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] so that it can be run to assess and validate any potential performance improvements